# Text scale up to fit a TextView and an EditText

Tags: android, text, textview, size, adt

I want to fit the `text size` of a `TextView` and an `EditText` to to match their bounds.
I searched a bit and found the code below. So I created a new class with the code below:

```
package com.example.test;


import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Layout.Alignment;
import android.text.StaticLayout;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AutoResizeTextView extends TextView {


        // Minimum text size for this text view
        public static final float MIN_TEXT_SIZE = 20;

        // Interface for resize notifications
        public interface OnTextResizeListener {
            public void onTextResize(TextView textView, float oldSize, float newSize);
        }

        // Our ellipse string
        private static final String mEllipsis = "...";

        // Registered resize listener
        private OnTextResizeListener mTextResizeListener;

        // Flag for text and/or size changes to force a resize
        private boolean mNeedsResize = false;

        // Text size that is set from code. This acts as a starting point for resizing
        private float mTextSize;

        // Temporary upper bounds on the starting text size
        private float mMaxTextSize = 0;

        // Lower bounds for text size
        private float mMinTextSize = MIN_TEXT_SIZE;

        // Text view line spacing multiplier
        private float mSpacingMult = 1.0f;

        // Text view additional line spacing
        private float mSpacingAdd = 0.0f;

        // Add ellipsis to text that overflows at the smallest text size
        private boolean mAddEllipsis = true;

        // Default constructor override
        public AutoResizeTextView(Context context) {
            this(context, null);
        }

        // Default constructor when inflating from XML file
        public AutoResizeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
        }

        // Default constructor override
        public AutoResizeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            mTextSize = getTextSize();
        }

        /**
         * When text changes, set the force resize flag to true and reset the text size.
         */
        @Override
        protected void onTextChanged(final CharSequence text, final int start, final int before, final int after) {
            mNeedsResize = true;
            // Since this view may be reused, it is good to reset the text size
            resetTextSize();
        }

        /**
         * If the text view size changed, set the force resize flag to true
         */
        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            if (w != oldw || h != oldh) {
                mNeedsResize = true;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Register listener to receive resize notifications
         * @param listener
         */
        public void setOnResizeListener(OnTextResizeListener listener) {
            mTextResizeListener = listener;
        }

        /**
         * Override the set text size to update our internal reference values
         */
        @Override
        public void setTextSize(float size) {
            super.setTextSize(size);
            mTextSize = getTextSize();
        }

        /**
         * Override the set text size to update our internal reference values
         */
        @Override
        public void setTextSize(int unit, float size) {
            super.setTextSize(unit, size);
            mTextSize = getTextSize();
        }

        /**
         * Override the set line spacing to update our internal reference values
         */
        @Override
        public void setLineSpacing(float add, float mult) {
            super.setLineSpacing(add, mult);
            mSpacingMult = mult;
            mSpacingAdd = add;
        }

        /**
         * Set the upper text size limit and invalidate the view
         * @param maxTextSize
         */
        public void setMaxTextSize(float maxTextSize) {
            mMaxTextSize = maxTextSize;
            requestLayout();
            invalidate();
        }

        /**
         * Return upper text size limit
         * @return
         */
        public float getMaxTextSize() {
            return mMaxTextSize;
        }

        /**
         * Set the lower text size limit and invalidate the view
         * @param minTextSize
         */
        public void setMinTextSize(float minTextSize) {
            mMinTextSize = minTextSize;
            requestLayout();
            invalidate();
        }

        /**
         * Return lower text size limit
         * @return
         */
        public float getMinTextSize() {
            return mMinTextSize;
        }

        /**
         * Set flag to add ellipsis to text that overflows at the smallest text size
         * @param addEllipsis
         */
        public void setAddEllipsis(boolean addEllipsis) {
            mAddEllipsis = addEllipsis;
        }

        /**
         * Return flag to add ellipsis to text that overflows at the smallest text size
         * @return
         */
        public boolean getAddEllipsis() {
            return mAddEllipsis;
        }

        /**
         * Reset the text to the original size
         */
        public void resetTextSize() {
            if(mTextSize > 0) {
                super.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, mTextSize);
                mMaxTextSize = mTextSize;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Resize text after measuring
         */
        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
            if(changed || mNeedsResize) {
                int widthLimit = (right - left) - getCompoundPaddingLeft() - getCompoundPaddingRight();
                int heightLimit = (bottom - top) - getCompoundPaddingBottom() - getCompoundPaddingTop();
                resizeText(widthLimit, heightLimit);
            }
            super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        }


        /**
         * Resize the text size with default width and height
         */
        public void resizeText() {
            int heightLimit = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom() - getPaddingTop();
            int widthLimit = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
            resizeText(widthLimit, heightLimit);
        }

        /**
         * Resize the text size with specified width and height
         * @param width
         * @param height
         */
        public void resizeText(int width, int height) {
            CharSequence text = getText();
            // Do not resize if the view does not have dimensions or there is no text
            if(text == null || text.length() == 0 || height <= 0 || width <= 0 || mTextSize == 0) {
                return;
            }

            // Get the text view's paint object
            TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();

            // Store the current text size
            float oldTextSize = textPaint.getTextSize();
            // If there is a max text size set, use the lesser of that and the default text size
            float targetTextSize = mMaxTextSize > 0 ? Math.min(mTextSize, mMaxTextSize) : mTextSize;

            // Get the required text height
            int textHeight = getTextHeight(text, textPaint, width, targetTextSize);

            // Until we either fit within our text view or we had reached our min text size, incrementally try smaller sizes
            while(textHeight > height && targetTextSize > mMinTextSize) {
                targetTextSize = Math.max(targetTextSize - 2, mMinTextSize);
                textHeight = getTextHeight(text, textPaint, width, targetTextSize);
            }

            // If we had reached our minimum text size and still don't fit, append an ellipsis
            if(mAddEllipsis && targetTextSize == mMinTextSize && textHeight > height) {
                // Draw using a static layout
                StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, textPaint, width, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mSpacingMult, mSpacingAdd, false);
                // Check that we have a least one line of rendered text
                if(layout.getLineCount() > 0) {
                    // Since the line at the specific vertical position would be cut off,
                    // we must trim up to the previous line
                    int lastLine = layout.getLineForVertical(height) - 1;
                    // If the text would not even fit on a single line, clear it
                    if(lastLine < 0) {
                        setText("");
                    }
                    // Otherwise, trim to the previous line and add an ellipsis
                    else {
                        int start = layout.getLineStart(lastLine);
                        int end = layout.getLineEnd(lastLine);
                        float lineWidth = layout.getLineWidth(lastLine);
                        float ellipseWidth = textPaint.measureText(mEllipsis);

                        // Trim characters off until we have enough room to draw the ellipsis
                        while(width < lineWidth + ellipseWidth) {
                            lineWidth = textPaint.measureText(text.subSequence(start, --end + 1).toString());
                        }
                        setText(text.subSequence(0, end) + mEllipsis);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Some devices try to auto adjust line spacing, so force default line spacing
            // and invalidate the layout as a side effect
            textPaint.setTextSize(targetTextSize);
            setLineSpacing(mSpacingAdd, mSpacingMult);

            // Notify the listener if registered
            if(mTextResizeListener != null) {
                mTextResizeListener.onTextResize(this, oldTextSize, targetTextSize);
            }

            // Reset force resize flag
            mNeedsResize = false;
        }

        // Set the text size of the text paint object and use a static layout to render text off screen before measuring
        private int getTextHeight(CharSequence source, TextPaint paint, int width, float textSize) {
            // Update the text paint object
            paint.setTextSize(textSize);
            // Measure using a static layout
            StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(source, paint, width, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mSpacingMult, mSpacingAdd, true);
            return layout.getHeight();
        }

    }
```

But what do I have to do from there in order for the code to work? This is my code and my XML file. What do I do wrong and what should I do?

Java:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import com.example.test.AutoResizeTextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public VideoView vv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  // Set Fullscreen mode, overiding title and BATTERY
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); // SCREEN NEVER GOES TO SLEEP MODE

     //*** BACKGROUND MOVIE, LOOPING AND SETTING LOCAL PATH ***
       vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        vv.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
            }
        });

       Uri url=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+ R.raw.bubblessd );
       vv.setVideoURI(url);
       vv.start();
       vv.requestFocus();
       //*** BACKGROUND MOVIE, LOOPING AND SETTING LOCAL PATH ***
    }


final EditText myet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
myet.resizeText();



}
```

and XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                         android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id = "@+id/main_menu_wrapper"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="100">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >


        <com.example.test.AutoResizeTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="#55000000"
            android:text="TextView" 
            />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="20"
                        android:background="#55000000"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLength="10"
                        android:shadowColor="#000"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold" >

       </EditText>  
           </LinearLayout> 

        </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried to get the same code to work a few times, and always ended up abandoning it because it doesn't work very well or introduces other bugs / glitchy behavior.

Comment: At least can you tell me how to use it with my main java code? Do I have to call it from the XML? and how? Or how do I call it from my main activity class? I'm noob at programming. What do I have to write down, so that I implement it for my TextView and EditText, even if it doesn't work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using it correctly. By defining it in your XML, you tell the inflater to use that class.

If you want to access it in Java, treat it like any other view:

```
    AutoResizeTextView textView = (AutoResizeTextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText("Hello, user!");
```

It will behave just like any other text view, except it is supposed to automatically resize the text.